# boolean expression to NOR gate (MUX)

Tags: multiplexer, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have a 2:1 MUX. It would be designed by using NOR gates. Inputs are X and Y. S, which is data select. When S is 0  F=X  , S is 1  F=Y. Until here, okey. I've found $$ F = S'X + SY $$
to make NOR, I've rewritten as $$ F = [(S + X') (S' + Y')]' $$  At this point , I'm stuck how I can make(draw) the expression by using just NOR gates. Actually, It can be drawn via softwares.But, I wonder that how I should think to draw. I need its logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A=input 1, B=input 2, S=switch
- from A create A' (nor port with 2 times A as input)
- from B create B' (nor port with 2 times B as input)
- from S create S' (nor port with 2 times S as input)
- create X=(S+A')' (nor port with A' as input and S as input)
- create Y=(S'+B')' (nor port with B' as input and S' as input)
- create Z=(X+Y)'=((S+A')'+(S'+B')')'
- create W=Z' (nor port with 2 times Z as input)
- then W=(((S+A')'+(S'+B')')')'=((S'.A)+(S.B))''=S'.A+S.B

Comment: is it right ? http://i.imgur.com/uoBXXtU.png

Comment: NewCoder's answer needs only 4 NOR gates. Nice.